# What factors can change a command's behavior in a windows command line environment?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, batch-file, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have a batch file that runs perfectly if I run it from the command line but if I run it from a visual studio build event, it fails.

I have assured the following things are the same between environments:

- both have administrator privileges
- both have identical environmental variables (checked using the SET command)
- both have identical working directories

Is there anything else I could be missing that is causing the script's behavior to change when run as a visual studio build event vs run by hand?

I have the script run asynchronously (using powershell start-process), and then have a lengthy sleep (ping) to be sure that visual studio is not interfering with the operating system environment (windows 10), but it does not help. However, though I do not remember changing anything, since I've started writing this question to double checking everything, the script seems to no longer run asynchronously, thus visual studio waits for it to complete. I am not sure if this is the problem or not, though.

The command in question that either succeeds or fails is `powershell start-process "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList '/c','write_reg.bat' -WorkingDirectory $(SolutionDir)scripts -UseNewEnvironment`

Comment: Very often problems arise when relative paths are used...

Comment: Thank you for your comment! However, my scripts do not fail because of path errors/missing files. The actual error message I get is a failure accessing the registry.

Comment: I suppose that depends on the contents of write_reg.bat